# Help needed with db structure

Tags: python, django, data-structures

I'm developing a web app that uses stock data. The stock data can be stored in:

1. Files
2. DB

The structure of the data is simple: there's a daily set and a weekly set. If files are used, then I can store a file per symbol/set, such as GOOGLE_DAILY and GOOGLE_WEEKLY. Each set includes a simple list of (Date, open/hight/low/close, volume, dividend) fields.

But how can I do it with DB? Should I use relational or other db? I thought about using 2 tables per each symbol, but that would generate thousands of tables, which doesn't feel right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a table per stock symbol, you just need one of the fields in the table to be the stock symbol. The table might be called `StockPrices` and its fields might be

- `ticker_symbol` - the stock ticker symbol
- `time` - the time of the stock quote
- `price` - the price of the stock at that time

As long as `ticker_symbol` is an indexed field you can do powerful queries like `SELECT time,price FROM StockPrices WHERE ticker_symbol='GOOG' ORDER BY time DESC` and they will be very efficient. You can also store as many symbols as you like in this table.

You could add other tables for dividends, volume information and such. In all cases you probably have a composite key of `ticker_symbol` and `time`.

Comment: In this case, a table can get very very big. For example, I now have the text files for the partial data I need, and this set is ~164MB. Considering that data in DB is stored more efficiently, it still will make one table to be in the order of few tens of megs. Is this going to be a problem for DB such as MySQL?

Comment: No, 164Mb is not a problem. We have a table at my work with ~2 billion rows, the total DB size is 500+ GB.

Also, in theory the tables can be partitioned over a cluster of machines since the queries you do will probably tend to deal with individual ticker symbols. Databases like Oracle and MySQL have support for this stuff.

Comment: MySql is only limited by the max size of a file of the OS: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html

Comment: Will this impact the speed of queries?

Comment: Your queries are all indexed by a stock symbol. The index is effectively an ordered list of all the stock symbols. Finding the start of data for a given symbol is a binary search through the index. Binary search is O(lg n), so if you have a billion entries that's about 30 iterations. This index will also be incredibly compact, only increasing in size in the order of the number of distinct stock symbols.

Comment: @sjr is it also true for concurrent users?

Comment: Yes, concurrent reads are fast. Speed of concurrent writes will depend on the locking mechanism used. Your data size is not a blip on the radar. Any RDBMS will handle 100s or 1000s of MB and 1000s of concurrent connections without breaking a sweat.

Comment: @Alex: You need to purchase a book on database design.  Do a Google search for "Database Design" and buy any book you find.  Your questions indicate that you need a lot more background in database design before you start coding.

Comment: @S.Lott: You are correct regarding my background, and the application I'm building has this purpose embedded - it allows me to learn a lot of aspects of building a web app.

Answer (score 0):

```
Make two tables:
```

#### DAILY_STOCK_DATA

```
DATETIME Date
CHAR(5)  Symbol #or whatever the max symbol length can be
INTEGER  Open
INTEGER  High
INTEGER  Low
INTEGER  Close
INTEGER  Volume
INTEGER  Dividend
```

Presuming that weekly data is averaged over 7 days? :

#### WEEKLY_STOCK_DATA

```
DATETIME Date  #date when the week started
CHAR(5)  Symbol #or whatever the max symbol length can be
INTEGER  AvgOpen
INTEGER  AvgHigh
INTEGER  AvgLow
INTEGER  AvgClose
INTEGER  AvgVolume
INTEGER  AvgDividend
```

Note: All the Open, Close etc. are integers. That's because they are meant to store
the values in the lowest currency coinage such as cents, instead of storing float data.